# Navigation Drawer With Checkboxs

Tags: android, checkbox, drawer

**I Put Checkbox in Navigation View and want to get the position Of true checkbox ,But when i click no checkbox its display only true and false .
I need checkx position in Listview Item Click Event .
I Done Almoast Xml Code , also call checkbox click event in customAdaptor
But Can't Find Main Activity Code . 
get position  of Checkbox when its checked true in navigation drawer?
**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

// nav drawer title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;

// slide menu items
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // nav drawer icons from resources
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // adding nav drawer items to array
    // Home
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1),true));
    // Find People
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1),true));
    // Photos
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1),true));
    // Communities, Will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true));
    // Pages
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1),true));
    // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1), true));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(7, -1), true));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[8], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(8, -1), true));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[9], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(9, -1), true));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[10], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(10, -1), true));



    // Recycle the typed array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_drawer);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView(0);
    }
}

/**
 * Slide menu item click listener
 * */
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        NavDrawerItem navDrawerItem = (NavDrawerItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),navDrawerItem.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        displayView(position);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/* *
 * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
 */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    case 1:

        break;
    case 2:

        break;
    case 3:

        break;
    case 4:

        break;
    case 5:

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

}
**this is my adapter**

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
    }

    ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    final CheckBox ch = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);


    imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());        
    txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());
    ch.setSelected(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCounterVisibility());

    ch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            boolean ans = ch.isChecked();
            navDrawerItems.get(position).setCounterVisibility(ans);
            Toast.makeText(context,String.valueOf(ch.isChecked()),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    // displaying count
    // check whether it set visible or not
    if(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCounterVisibility()){

    }else{
        // hide the counter view

    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Where are you declaring the check box and getting its value?

Comment: in xml and in adapter of mdrawerlist

Comment: Shouldnt you be posting them if your query is regarding that. Also try editing your question to be more clear.

Comment: now i put adapter code also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define one `Interface` class:

```
public Interface OnChckBoxClickListener
{

public void onCheckBoxClick(int position, boolean isChecked);
}
```

After that create object of interface in adapter, see following code:

```
adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems, new OnCheckBoxClickLisener()
{
public void OnCheckBoxClick(int position, boolean isChecked)
{
//print here position and isChecked
// also do here code what you want
}
});
```

After that registered listener in constructor of adapter:

```
public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context conext, ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems, OnCheckBoxClickLisener listener)
{
this.context = context;
this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
this.lisetner = listener;
}
```

Then set Listener to OnClickOfCheckBox in `getView`:

```
ch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            boolean ans = ch.isChecked();
            //navDrawerItems.get(position).setCounterVisibility(ans);
            listener.OnCheckBoxClick(position, ans);
Toast.makeText(context,String.valueOf(ch.isChecked()),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks you For your Code

Comment: does it helps you? if yes then why people giving negative voting to me?

Comment: Yes its Perfectly Work And help me